# How to set a password via environment variables for a cifs mount in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, sudo, cifs

I've been trying to set the PASSWD environment variable like it says you can in the mount.cifs manual, but it still prompts me for a password and ignores the environment variable I set before it.

```
sudo /bin/mount -t cifs '//servername/share' '/home/users/username/share' --verbose -o user='username',domain=domain,sec=ntlmv2,soft
```

I forgot to mention. The password contains a ',' which I understand is a delimiter. I think I've misunderstood the cifs manual. Does this mean credentials file is the only way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Your environment is reset when you use `sudo` by default. Edit the `sudoers` file with the `visudo` command and add the following near the top:

```
Defaults env_keep += 'PASSWD'
```

Alternatively you could use something like this:

```
youruser this_host = SETENV: /bin/mount
```

See also `sudo -E` in `man 5 sudoers`.